# Regex to match everything right of a "-" but whole string if no "-" exists

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a way to have a regex that returns the whole string, if no `"-"` is found in the string. But if there is a `"-"`, it should only return everything to the right of that `"-"`.

For example:

- `"Text"` should return `"Text"`
- `"Sample-Text"` should return `"Text"`

So far, i figured out how to solve the second part: `(?<=-).*` returns everything after a `"-"`.
However, i am completely stuck figuring out how to combine that and return everything if there is no `"-"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a character set that excludes `"-"`:

```
[^-]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yRm59e/1